# How to print " (quot) instead of &quot; using jquery in input text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to fetch data using jquery but I'm having a problem with htmlentities because it shows `&quot;` instead of `"` in jquery.

Here is my code for input text:

```html
<input type="text" name="material_name[]" id="material_name<?=$x?>" autocomplete="off" readonly="true" class="form-control oninput" />
```

And here's JQUERY Fetching the value

```js
          $.ajax({
                    url: 'fetchSelectedOrder.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {productId : productId},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response) {
                        // setting the rate value into the rate input field
                        
                        $("#material_name"+row).val(response.material_name);

                    } // /success
                }); // /ajax function to fetch the product data 
            }
```

fetchSelectedOrder.php

```html
<?php  

require_once 'checker.php';

$productId = $_POST['productId'];

$sql = "SELECT material_name FROM tbl_materials WHERE m_id = $productId";
$result = $controller->runQuery($sql);
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() >= 1) {
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} // if num_rows

echo json_encode($row);
```

Data From Database:
[image]

I use htmlentities to prevent quote inside database.

How can I fetch `&quot;` as `"`?

Comment: use double quotes to parse data eg: `echo "&quot;";` \\ will result to `"`

Comment: That's what `htmlentities()` is supposed to do. You shouldn't use it when storing in the DB, you should only use it when displaying data that you don't want to be interpreted.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, `htmlentities` doesn't do anything to stop a SQL injection.

Comment: @Barmar: that would be [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) in fact...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No, that goes the other way. `htmlentities()` is supposed to turn `"` to `&quot;`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes... I agree. But OP wants to decode... If I'm not wrong. He has it encoded in DB... And want to show the un-encoded char now...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette My point was that he shouldn't encode it in the first place. The whole point of calling `htmlentities()` is to perform that replacement. If you don't want it, don't do it.

Comment: Agree to that ;)

Comment: Yes but I am also trying to stop html execution

Comment: *«...trying to stop html execution»* --- I hear the X-Files theme song in my head... What do you mean with HTML execution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `html_entity_decode()` to convert it back to the original text.

However, I recommend that you stop using `htmlentities()` when storing into the database. You don't need to prevent having quotes in the database. If you're getting syntax errors when you try to store it, you should fix the code to use parametrized statements rather than substituting variables into the string. And if you *must* substitute variables, you should use a proper escaping function, either `mysqli::real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote()`.

If you're trying to prevent XSS, call `htmlentities()` when you're displaying the output on a web page. If you're using JavaScript to display the results on a web page, use the `textContent` DOM property or the jQuery `.text()` method, rather than `innerHTML` or `.html()`. If you're assigning to the `value` property, it never gets executed so you don't need to do any encoding.

Comment: You don't need to store entities in the database to prevent that. I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to decode html:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  // handle case of empty input
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
$("#material_name"+row).val(htmlDecode(response.material_name));
```

That will display html as real text.

Answer (score 0):

You could decode the HTML entities coming from the DB on server side.

```
<?php

require_once 'checker.php';

$productId = $_POST['productId'];

$sql = "SELECT material_name FROM tbl_materials WHERE m_id = $productId";
$result = $controller->runQuery($sql);
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() >= 1) {
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} // if num_rows

// Run html_entity_decode on all $row values
foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
  $row[$k] = html_entity_decode($v);
}

echo json_encode($row);
```

That also is a "patch" for a DB having bad values... But unlike the other answer, which relies on the end user's device, here is a server-side solution.

---

And please read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent injection...